# appends n-th line from the file x at the end of the file y

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, execute-command, at-command

I have been asked to write a command that appends the n-th line (`MYN`) from a file (`x`)to another file (`y`). Here's what I've done so far:

```
MYN=4
hey=$(awk 'NR==$MYN' x)
echo "$hey" >> y
```

But why doesn't this work?

Comment: If it doesn't work, what *does* it do instead?

Comment: the awk doesn't recognise the variable MYN. It works fine without the variable..

Comment: To pass a variable to `awk` use the `-v` option: `hey=$(awk -v MYN=$MYN 'NR==MYN' x)`

Comment: @kos I tried this already, but my terminal prints "awk: invalid -v option" :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to pass a variable to `awk` in order to use it within the script, you can use `awk` with the `-v` option:

```
hey=$(awk -v MYN=$MYN 'NR==MYN' x)
```

Answer (score 2):

I see your problem, you're using single quotes. They won't allow the Bash variable `$MYN` to expand. You can complicate things by telling `awk` a new variable, or because it's so simple, you can just switch to double-quotes:

```
awk "NR==$MYN" x
```

---

I'd have [used `sed`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6022431/12870) but I can't see any obvious issues with your logic

```
MYN=4
sed "${MYN}q;d" x >> y
```

---

It seems to work as expected:

```
$ for i in $(seq 1 10); do echo $i >> x; done
$ sed "${MYN}q;d" x
4
```